# How to show a list of options when a marker is clicked?

Tags: android, list

I am creating an application with Android Google maps API that could let me map Accessibility Problems of streets. 
My program allows users today to put n markers on a map, search an specific place or put a marker where the user currently is (MyLocation button).
 I’m now searching how to create a list on google maps API for Android. The idea is that a list will appear when the marker (placed somewhere on the map) Is tapped, so the user will be able to choose one of the options of this list, and the value that the user chose will be stored. The options represent the kind of accessibility problem that the user found.
Does anyone already used lists somewhere along with this API?
Here is my full code:

```
package com.example.i841838.myapplication; import android.app.Dialog; import android.content.Intent; import android.content.SharedPreferences; import android.content.pm.PackageManager; import android.net.Uri; import android.os.Bundle; import android.os.Environment; import android.provider.MediaStore; import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat; import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult; import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil; import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory; import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener; import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener; import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment; import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng; import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.File;

import static com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable; import static com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    int locationCount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

// Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

// Showing status
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { // Google Play Services are available

// Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

// Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();

// Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

// Opening the sharedPreferences object
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("location", 0);

// Getting number of locations already stored
            locationCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("locationCount", 0);

// Getting stored zoom level if exists else return 0
            String zoom = sharedPreferences.getString("zoom", "0");

// If locations are already saved
            if(locationCount!=0){

                String lat = "";
                String lng = "";

// Iterating through all the locations stored
                for(int i=0;i<locationCount;i++){

// Getting the latitude of the i-th location
                    lat = sharedPreferences.getString("lat"+i,"0");

// Getting the longitude of the i-th location
                    lng = sharedPreferences.getString("lng"+i,"0");

// Drawing marker on the map
                    drawMarker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng)));
                }

// Moving CameraPosition to last clicked position
                googleMap.moveCamera(newLatLng(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng))));

// Setting the zoom level in the map on last position is clicked
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(Float.parseFloat(zoom)));
            }

        }

        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                locationCount++;

// Drawing marker on the map
                drawMarker(point);

/** Opening the editor object to write data to sharedPreferences */
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

// Storing the latitude for the i-th location
                editor.putString("lat"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), Double.toString(point.latitude));

// Storing the longitude for the i-th location
                editor.putString("lng"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), Double.toString(point.longitude));

// Storing the count of locations or marker count
                editor.putInt("locationCount", locationCount);

/** Storing the zoom level to the shared preferences */
                editor.putString("zoom", Float.toString(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom));

/** Saving the values stored in the shared preferences */
                editor.commit();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Marcador adicionado ao mapa!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

// Removing the marker and circle from the Google Map
                googleMap.clear();

// Opening the editor object to delete data from sharedPreferences
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

// Clearing the editor
                editor.clear();

// Committing the changes
                editor.commit();

// Setting locationCount to zero
                locationCount=0;

            }
        });

    }

    private void drawMarker(LatLng point){ // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

// Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
        markerOptions.position(point);

// Adding marker on the Google Map
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
     }
```

Comment: Since you can create a custom infoWindow for your map's marker, you can create a ListVeiw inside it

Comment: But how can it is shown exactly when a marker is clicked? I want a list of options to appear when a tap a marker on the map, but I do not know how to do it.